# Where is the implementation of isEven in int.dart class?

Tags: dart

If you open `int.dart` class source code, you'll find `isEven` is written as:

```
/** Returns true if and only if this integer is even. */
bool get isEven;
```

I want to know in which class this method is implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implemented in the *implementation class* which implements the `int` interface.
Which class that is (or if there really is a class) depends on the backend.

The VM has a number of classes implementing `int`, but all of them get their [`isEven` implementation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk_nnbd/lib/_internal/vm/lib/integers.dart#L143) from the same superclass.

When compiling to JavaScript, integers are represented directly by JavaScript numbers.
The compiled code treats those as Dart objects implementing the internal class, and that too [implements `isEven`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk_nnbd/lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/js_number.dart#L475).

Comment: Right implementation responsibility is on the subclass, `int` is `abstract` in source code

Comment: Only a Dart team member could have answered this question.

Comment: Well, it is possible for outsiders since I found the same two classes and posted an answer right before lrn. But lrn's answer was more detailed described so I deleted my post. Just wanted to say that the Dart SDK code base are not complete impossible to navigate for outsiders. :D

Comment: I agree that @julemand101 actually answered it quite well too, without being a Dart team member. Kudoz!

Comment: @julemand101 I didn't see your answer, hope you didn't mind my comment ;) To LRN sir, can you post a link that mentions in which native language Dart compiles to for different platforms like for Android, iOS, web, linux, macOS, windows, etc.

Comment: I don't actually know how all platforms work. Dart only compiles to either JavaScript (for the web) or to "native". The "native" is most likely an internal representation of the VM state (a "snapshot") or preprocessed Dart source (a `.dill` file) which is bundled with a natively compiled Dart VM runtime. I don't know of certain which platforms do what, but I don't believe Dart is ever compiled to another high-level language than JavaScript.